# briannesbitt/Carbon with Laravel Blade Templates - Formatting custom dateTime column

Tags: php, datetime, laravel

I am trying to display a formatted date in a Blade View. I am using Laravel 4.1.

I have created an alias in my `config/app.php`

```
'Carbon'          => 'Carbon\Carbon'
```

I migrate my appointments table as follows:

```
$table->dateTime('appointment');
```

View

```
@foreach($appointments as $appointment)
<tr>
        <td>{{{ $appointment->customer_name }}}</td> 
    <td>{{{ $appointment->consultant->consultant_name }}}</td>
    <td>{{{ $appointment->appointment }}}</td> {{-- Displays as seen in mysql --}}
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

If I try to format the date as follows, an exception is thrown:

```
<td>{{{ $appointment->appointment->format('Y-m-d') }}}</td>

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

If I change `{{{ $appointment->appointment->format('Y-m-d') }}}` to `{{{ $appointment->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}}`, the date is formatted correctly.

How can I get laravel and Carbon to treat and format `appointment` as a date which I can format?

Comment: I think I may have it working... In my `Appointment` Model, I override the `getDates` method as follows:  `public function getDates()
 {
     return array('created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at', 'appointment');
 }`

Comment: yea you need to add it to that array so it converts it to a carbon object.   you should submit your own answer and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your `Appointment` model the property

```
protected $dates = array('appointment');
```

This is picked up and added to the default fields treated as dates (`created_at`, `updated_at` and `deleted_at`) and then converted to a `Carbon` instance automatically.

You could instead override the `getDates` method, as you suggest in your comment, but there's no need since you still want all the default fields to be treated as dates. By setting this property there's no need to repeat them. See [the source code for `getDates`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2509).